# Combine 2 harddrive into 1

Tags: windows, combine

I wanted to install Windows 10 on my new computer.
Inside has 2 harddrive that has 1TB storage.

How do I combine 2 harddrive into 1 harddrive before I install Windows on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer has a raid controller, you can create a striped partition using the RAID controller's setup screen.

In order to do this, you need to access the bios/uefi and set it from AHCI to RAID. Then, during boot, you see a new prompt with key combination to access the raid controller. From there you can setup your new volume.

If your computer does not have a RAID controller, you can also do this in software.

First, install windows onto one of the two disks, as you normally would.

Now, in windows, you need to convert both disks into dynamic disks. Do note, that in order to convert them back to regular disks, they will have to be wiped. Going into a dynamic disk is basically a one-way trick, and is only supported by Windows. Dual booting Linux is not going to work anymore.

Once Both disks are converted into a dynamic disk, you need to reinstall windows once more. This time, the windows setup will see both disks as one and allows you to create a partition that spans both disks. So delete all partitions previously made, and on the empty space, create the new partition that spans both drives.

Do keep in mind, that if one of the harddisks fails, all data becomes inaccessible. It might be better to just use them as separate disks.